# Okay to use Macro to identify iOS Device?

Tags: ios, xcode, macros

I have a universal app where, in several parts of the code, I have to check the device type to render UI elements. 
Earlier, I had a bool variable(`isDeviceIPad`), assigned on `viewDidLoad` to get the job done, but came across some cases where the variable wasn't assigned properly(my View Controller had a complex flow).

So instead I thought I might use a macro, so the `isDeviceIPad` macro(instead of bool variable) will never be wrong:

```
#define isDeviceIPad ([[UIDevice currentDevice]userInterfaceIdiom]==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
```

Is it okay to use a Macro like this? Any reason why I shouldn't(performance considerations etc.)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That macro will work fine and it will have no extra performance issue. When your app is compiled, each use of the macro will be replaced with the macro's definition. It's like a big search and replace.

Though you should just use:

```
#define isDeviceIPad (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
```

Comment: Actually my Macro definition resolves to a bool value, so I can simply use `if(isDeviceIPad){....}`
But thanks! I was just wondering if accessing the object property of `currentDevice` over and over adds a performance overhead.

Comment: What I posted resolves to a BOOL as well. I'll update my answer by adding parentheses. Calling currentDevice is trivial. The performance is nothing to worry about.

Comment: How is UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() better than `[[UIDevice currentDevice]userInterfaceIdiom]`? Is it a predefined macro?

Comment: Yes, `UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()` is a predefined macro provided by Apple. It's in their docs. It actually just calls `userInterfaceIdiom` on the current device. At the moment, using theirs or yours makes no difference. But I prefer theirs because it is possible the definition could change someday (not likely, but possible).

Comment: @VinodVishwanath [`UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/macro/UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM) is a little better because it first checks that `UIDevice` responds to `-userInterfaceIdiom`. Follow the link for the definition.

Comment: @Caleb That will probably go away since this was all added in iOS 3.2. I doubt the need for that check will be useful much longer.

Answer (score 0):

this is the proper syntax (no spaces && no 'i' before pad or phone && no extra punctuation)

```
   #define isDeviceIPad UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad
   #define isDeviceIPhone UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone
```

Comment: Putting parentheses around the entire macro definition is really important.  It prevents the macro from being misinterpreted when used as part of a larger expression.  [Here is a more detailed explanation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.2/cpp/Operator-Precedence-Problems.html#Operator-Precedence-Problems).  I don't see why you want to take out the spaces; it makes no difference to the compiler, and it hurts readability for humans.

Comment: The spaces & parentheses make no difference (except human readability), but you are right about removing the 'i'. `UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad` and `UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone` is what I did use (didn't bother to check spellings because of xcode autocomplete).

Thank you for pointing it out!

Comment: I've made the minor corrections to Maddy's answer: awaiting peer review.

Comment: @VinodVishwanath You are mistaken about the parentheses; MGM is wrong to remove them.  See the link in my comment.

Comment: @Zack, in this example, there is only one operator: the equality operator. There is no ambiguity in the macro definition.

I've tested the macro without the parentheses, both with and without spaces, and it works as expected.

Comment: @Zack, on second thoughts, you are right! I missed where you said "when used as part of a larger expression."

It worked for me because my `if()` checks are simple, but if I write something like `if(isDeviceiPhone + 1)`, the macro goes wrong. (Note, the condition itself is rather meaningless, although syntactically valid). 
So yes, using parentheses is the correct practice. Thanks!

Comment: @VinodVishwanath That's right.  Your code right now may not need the protection that the parentheses provide, but it's still good practice to put them in, just in case things change in the future.

Comment: The parentheses are need if you want to do something like: `if (!isDeviceIPad) {`.

Comment: @VinodVishwanath I just fixed the typo in my answer. Thanks for noticing (5 months later) :)